# adding a quit timer that closes a photo

Tags: python

After many hours of searching online and in my python book I can't seem to find the answer to my question which is what do I add to my code so I can put in a timer that automatically closes the photo?  It pulls itself up but then I have to manually close the photo to get back to my main program. Any help would be appreciated.

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('battleship load screen.png')
img.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using PIL alone - `img.show()` is just launching another program, it's intended for debugging really, not for presenting things to the user.

From [the docs](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm).

> Displays an image. This method is mainly intended for debugging
>   purposes.
>
> On Unix platforms, this method saves the image to a temporary PPM
>   file, and calls the xv utility.
>
> On Windows, it saves the image to a temporary BMP file, and uses the
>   standard BMP display utility to show it.
>
> This method returns None.

If you want to display an image and have control over it, [use a graphical toolkit](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/5866) and construct a UI for your purpose. I've linked there to an example using PySide, a set of QT bindings, but of course you could use any toolkit - each will be different.